# How to execute a .CQL file using cmd (file.bat)

Tags: batch-file, cassandra, datastax

I want to execute . CQL file using a batch file
I tried this code but i have always an error message

```
cd C:\Users\admin\.devcenter\DevCenter\CQLScripts
cqlsh 189.3.2.402 9044
cqlsh -f file.cql
```

the error message is the following:
**"cqlsh n'est reconnu en tant que commande interne"**

PS: I am beginner in cql ..

Thanks!

Comment: I assume cqlsh is inside C:\Users\admin\.devcenter\DevCenter\CQLScripts directory. Please try to run with full path `C:\Users\admin\.devcenter\DevCenter\CQLScripts\cqlsh 189.3.2.402 9044 -f \path\to\file.cql`

Comment: Just in case the current directory prior to the first line in your example was on a different drive/volume, I'd sugggest you use `CD/D "C:\Users\admin\.devcenter\DevCenter\CQLScripts"` instead. Apart from that, I thought the correct method was to use `python cqlsh` as already mentioned in an answer and that would obviously depend upon the full path to python being set within `%PATH%`.

Comment: @Apolozeus there is always the same error message!

Comment: @Compo what is I must install for python than how can i configure python in %PATH% please?

Comment: @Compo I have configured python and now i have a new error message *"python: can't open file 'cqlsh': [Error 2] No such file or directory*

Answer (score 2):

Does your PATH environment variable point to your python installation? If not, try the following:

```
python cqlsh [options] [host [port]]
```

Comment: A new error message is displayed *python: can't open file 'cqlsh': [Error 2] No such file or directory*                                                                                                          The command that I have excuted `python cqlsh -f file.cql 189.3.2.402 9044`

Comment: Where is Cassandra installed? Try changing to the Cassandra install bin directory and then execute the python command. Something like the following steps:1) cd c:\cassandra\bin   2) python cqlsh -f file.cql 189.3.2.402 9044